# wordpress myAjax is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working in child theme and put following code for admin ajax js

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
/*  echo "string". get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/jquery.bxslider.css';
    exit();*/
    wp_register_script('flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexisel.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
    wp_enqueue_script('bxslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array(),true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bxslider');

    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(),true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');
    //wp_localize_script('admin_script', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );

    wp_localize_script('admin_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script('admin_script');

} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts', 999 );
```

but it given me error like

```
ReferenceError: myAjax is not defined
    url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
```

I used myAjax declaration in my custom js..

```
jQuery('#load_more_posts').on('click',function(){
    var lng =jQuery(".post_item").length;

    jQuery.ajax({
      type : "post",
      url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
       data : {action: "load_more_posts_home",count : lng},
 }).done(function(response){
      var posts = JSON.parse(response);

      for( var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ )
      {
        if( posts[i] == "0" )
          jQuery("#load_more_posts").fadeOut();
        else
          jQuery("#load_more_posts").before(posts[i]);
      }

    });
});
```

so how could i resolve this issue in my wordpress child theme.

Comment: can I see your declaration of your myAjax variable

Comment: i put declaration of myAjax in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom'); //Name of the script. Should be unique.here is 'custom'
wp_localize_script('custom', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));  // remove admin_script and add unique javascript file.
```

Here above code localized the object:'myAjax' in script "custom". and you can access property "ajax_url" by adding below code in custom script file.

in **custom.js**

```
alert(myAjax.ajaxurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `admin_script` use `ajax-script` like this

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'myAjax',array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Otherwise you can add `wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script');` before you have define your ajax script localize function.